# How to import an external thirdparty library that has no exports / modules into an Angular2 app?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to import an external library. The library is simply a js file that defines an object `var library = {...}`, it has no exports, modules or anything like that whatsoever.

I don't want to use a `script` tag on the `index.html` file. How should I import this in my Angular 2 app, in a clean way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular-CLI, you can inject these dependencies by including your .js files in `angular-cli.json`.

Take a look at [3rd Party Libraries](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation).

Comment: 1. Not using angular-cli. 
2. That seems to help with normal libraries that respect standards, what I'm asking is about the ones that don't and literally have no modules or exports or whatever in them. Does that method work with those too?

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand what you mean, but this approach is applicable for alle kinds of js files as far as I know. I've recently used it for Chart.js and Bootstrap

Comment: try to load the library with cdn in the index.html file

Comment: Chart.js has module.exports and also puts it on window, the library I'm looking at doesn't have that.

@YoavSchniederman I'm especially trying to not do that. Putting it on the window and in the index wouldn't be a great idea.